# How do I "stabilize" the interpolator that uses the roots?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, roots, interpolation, weierstrass-factorization

In a previous question, I have been instructed that, in order to pass through all and only the distinct points $(x_{1}, 0) ... (x_{k}, 0)$  with a non-constant continuous function, I can simply use the product of the $(x -x_{n})$.

Now, I have actually tried that, but it seems that the interpolator starts oscillating like crazy with just 4-5 terms, after which it becomes pretty "inusable" in practice.

How can I modify this interpolator to have very "regular" and "stable" behavior? More similar to a $sin(x)$ wave, for instance.

Added: The ideal behavior for my applications would be a closed-form function that can be used with a large number of points, at each point changes sign, remains limited, but also does not vanish to zero.

[image]

Other related question.

In this case, the interpolator is zero when at least one of $k$ conditions of the type $(x = x_{n})$ is satisfied.

Given arbitrary $(x_{1}, 0) ... (x_{k}, 0)$, how can I find a similar interpolator that is zero at when least one of $k$ conditions of the type $((x = x_{n}) ~ and ~(x$ is an even integer$))$ is satisfied.

Comment: Reading up on the Runge phenomenon might prove enlightening. ([Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon) / [Video by Stand Up Maths](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F_43oTnTXiw))

Comment: You could use factors like $1-x/x_n$, $1-x^2/x_n^2$, …

Comment: Thank you. First time I hear about the "Runge phenomenon". Good to know this is a known thing. Since sin(x) apparently can be expressed as an infinite polynomial, I was expecting should be relatively easy to obtain a more "stable" curve. How come that is not "exploding" ?

Comment: @ FShrike I am trying that, but it seems to remain "explosive" (just after 4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to force the interpolator to remain within certain bounds, you can just use $\prod_{i=1}^k \sin(x-x_i)$. In the following pictures you can see, using $x_1 = 1, 2, \cdots, 5$, the different behaviour of $\prod_{i=1}^{5} (x - x_i)$ and $\prod_{i=1}^{5} \sin(x-x_i)$.

Another possibility could be using cubic splines. The last picture is obtained for the same set of points adding the extra constraint that it passes in $(0.5,1)$ (otherwise the result would be the zero function).

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Any hints on why the downvote?

Comment: I did not downvote it, however, I am trying it on Desmos and it seems it does not have the desired roots (not passing through all and only the points). Probably a multiplication by pi is needed (?), but that would work only if xi are equispaced integers (?)

Comment: @Jada There was no requirement in the OP regarding passing through zero in other points... the only requirement was that it passed in all the points $(x_i,0)$, which does happen in this case. When $x = x_i$ one of the factors is $\sin(x_i -x_i) = 0$.

Comment: Ok, I see your point. I made the question more precise, I was assuming it was understood that those must be the only roots, as that was also specified in a previous question.

Comment: Note also that for a large number of points, it becomes rapidly flat (a constant).

Comment: @Jada, becoming nearly flat does not make it a constant... I added another possibility, using cubic splines. In this case the degree of polynomials is kept low, three in this case. The interpolator is a polynomial of degree three between interpolation points and is globally continuous up to the second derivative.

Comment: Yes, that is true mathematically, but since I need to apply numerical methods to find roots, having it indistinguishable from zero (that is < machine epsilon) becomes a problem. What I was looking for is an explicit closed-form function, I can write simply in code (whatever the number of points). Passing through all and only the points and not "exploding", nor being almost zero everywhere.

Comment: @Jada The cubic spline is computed solving a system of linear equations, it may be a good candidate.

Comment: Indeed. For numerical application, I was looking for something simpler, like an explicit closed-form expression. Usable for instance on an array of 1 million points or so. Perhaps your product of sin() of differences might still be used as a good candidate (limiting the search in a range) if multiplied for some factor, to avoid it vanishing.

Comment: The ideal behavior for my applications would be a closed-form function that at each point changes sign (so that, inversely, we can retrieve the roots by bisection) and remain, limited but not too small.